# Github, how to get commit Id of first commit within pull request?

Tags: git, github

Let's say someone opens a pull request from a feature branch to dev branch.
This pull request contains one commit (0d636ac). Later on this someone commits X amount of times to the feature branch, all these commits get synced to the pull request.

How can I get/reference of the first commit within the pull request (0d636ac)?

Visual: `b0` is where the feature-branch gets created from `a1`

```
a0 --- a1
        \
         b0 --- ,..., --- bN
```

I want the commit id of `b0`

Comment: Pull requests are not a feature of git itself, they exist in tools built on top of git, so you *probably* need to talk to some specific API or use a specific CLI for your platform (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, ...). You *might* get away with assuming that the root of the branch in relation to the target branch (if you know it) is the root of the PR. Don't know if that's always true.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! I will update my question then to reflect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git log a1..bN --reverse -n 1`. This should give you the hash of the first commit present in `bN` which is not present in `a1`.

`git log a..b` displays commits between `a` and `b`.

`--reverse` makes it start at the first commit instead of the last one.

`-n 1` limits the output to a single commit.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting for details.

Comment: Add `--topo-order` if appropriate, or `--parents` for machine reading; consider using `git rev-list`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the only issue I see with this is that during the time of evaluation I don't now what bN is, would writing git log a1..HEAD be equivalent?

Comment: @MisterButter : if you are on the MR branch, yes

Comment: @dan1st: `a1..bN` will not contain `a1`, I think you don't need the `--skip=1`

Comment: @MisterButter you can use any reference to it. This could be the branch name of the PR or HEAD if you already checked it out.

Comment: @dan1st thank you for taking your time to help, This have been very useful!

Comment: The case is to use this in a git action, so the repo gets checkout and then the references will be origin/dev..origin/feature-branch

Comment: If you checked out the branch, `b` should be `HEAD`.